# How to provide multistage in with pipeline of JavaMongoRDD in Java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am facing issue to provide multi stage operatotrs in JavaMongoRDD.pipeline method in java.

The Scala code I found for writing multi stage in pipeline is

```
val aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(
  Document.parse("{ '$match': {'x.t': { '$gte' : 1448908200000}, '$lt': 1448994600000 } }"), 
  Document.parse("{ '$project': {'_id':0, 'b':'$a.f', 'v':'$a.m', 'q':'$r.q' } }")
))
```

I tried:

```
String aggregateQuery = "{ $match: {  $and: [{gatewaytime : { $gte : " + startTime
            + ", $lte : " + endTime + " }} , {mac : {$in:" + deviceMacs + "} } ]} }";

JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(getJSC());
JavaMongoRDD<Document> aggregatedRdd = rdd
    .withPipeline(Collections.singletonList(Document.parse(aggregateQuery)))
    .withPipeline(Collections.singletonList(Document.parse("{$sort: {gatewaytime : -1}")));
```

but not working, always only last pipeline results are there.

It is not possible to provide two document parse in `singletonList` so, how to provide `$match` and `$sort` in pipeline in Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JavaMongoRDD#withPipeline` method takes a Java `List` so can be used in the same way as the Scala version:

```
JavaMongoRDD<Document> aggregatedRdd = rdd
    .withPipeline(Arrays.asList(Document.parse(aggregateQuery),
                                Document.parse("{$sort: {gatewaytime : -1}")));
```

Note: `withPipeline` will overwrite any existing pipeline, so you must pass the complete pipeline to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two potential solutions. First...

```
val mongoRDD = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse(pipeline1),Document.parse(pipeline2)))
```

...or...

```
val mongoRDD = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse(pipeline1))).withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse(pipeline2)))
```